# Does :focus work with specificity as :hover does?

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem. I want the `input-group-addon` that holds an icon (search icon, calendar icon, etc) to inherit the hover, focus, and active states of its input field by specificity. I have it working for hover but for some reason specificity is ignoring the focus state. I thought it was a conflicting css directive in my code but I isolated the problem in CODEPEN and it does it there as well.

In summary, I want the input group addon border to change to yellow seamlessly with its input field when I focus on it (tab or click), as it does when I hover on it.

**My HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group controls">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Name" />
    <span class="input-group-addon right search"></span>
</div>
```

**My CSS** (Use Chrome if possible. I didn't include here the corssbrowser stuff to make it simpler to read) Also, this is originally built on SCSS:

```
.mar40 {
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.form-control {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #8f8f8f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    -webkit-border-radius: 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 34px;
    -ms-border-radius: 34px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    background: #211E1E;
}

.form-control:focus,
.form-control:hover {
    border-color: rgba(248, 151, 29, 0.77);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.form-control .input-group-addon {
    background: #8f8f8f;
    border-color: #555555;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.controls .input-group-addon.right.search {
    background: #30373e;
    border: 2px solid #8f8f8f;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    min-width: 0;
}

.controls .input-group-addon.right.search:before {
    content: "\f4a4";
    font-family: 'Ionicons';
    font-size: 16px;
}

.controls:focus .input-group-addon.right,
.controls:hover .input-group-addon.right,
.controls:active .input-group-addon.right {
    border: 2px solid rgba(248, 151, 29, 0.77) !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.controls:focus .input-group-addon.right:before,
.controls:hover .input-group-addon.right:before,
.controls:active .input-group-addon.right:before {
    color: rgba(248, 151, 29, 0.77);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Desired effect illustration on hover/focus/active
[image]

This is what I am getting on focus
[image]

And the handy dandy [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qZPoQj)

Thanks!

Comment: `:focus` and `:hover` has equal specificity. I can't reproduce the problem with your live demo.

Comment: hmmm. really? That's odd. Are you using chrome. Maybe it's a browser thing. And I always though focus and hover have the same specificity too but I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't do it for me. By the way I added a picture of what I am getting on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:focus` applies for the `input` and not the parent container and so your selector group should be as follows. (*Note the changed selector in the first line*)

```
.form-control:focus + .input-group-addon.right,
.controls:hover .input-group-addon.right,
.controls:active .input-group-addon.right {
  border: 2px solid rgba(248, 151, 29, 0.77) !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

As far as I know, when you `:hover` the child you are also indirectly hovering on the parent and so the `.controls:hover .input-group-addon.right` also works when `.form-control:hover` is applicable. Thus both the `.form-control` and `.input-group-addon.right` get the border.

But when you focus on the `.form-control`, the focus selector applies only to the `input` and doesn't get applied to its container. Thus only the `.form-control` gets the border and not the `.input-group-addon`. So, the selector must be changed to style the `.input-group-addon` based on the `input` and not the container's focus.

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/MyEGWy)

Comment: This is awesome. It did fix the problem and I understand it. It was in fact a problem of specificity, but a human error instead, not the selector. Good stuff! I do however have a minor addition. In some cases I have input group addons on the left which changes the specificity a little. Duplicating the code you provided with the .left class didn't fix it because it's the way the HTML is written. In other words, the span tag holding the input group addon is placed above the input field

Comment: I will accept this answer regardless, I just thougt you might wanted to weigh in on that tweak. I'll add the HTML to the codepen

Comment: @LOTUSMS: Yes, I have used the sibling selector (`+`). CSS sibling selectors select only elements that are below the reference element in the DOM (a child, a descendant or a later sibling). So, it won't work if the .`input-group-addon` element is before the `.form-control`. Maybe you can tweak the floats (that is, set the `float: right`) or set `position: absolute` etc to retain the `.input-group-addon` below the `.form-control` but still get it to display before the `.form-control`.

Comment: I thought of that. It is doable but an ugly solution. Perhaps the only solution. I'll work around it and see what I can come with. Thanks!